# Organizar arquivos de layout no Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Seguinte,

Eu tenho um projeto que no fim vai ser enorme. atualmente eu terminei 1 modulo de um total de 4 módulos e ele já ta cheio de layouts, etc. Segue uma imagem só para vcs terem noção do tanto de arquivo que tem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ainda tem muito mais layouts pra baixo ainda...

Enfim, eu gostaria de separar tudo que esta dentro de res/layout dentro de subpastas. é possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com Gradle de uma olhada neste [projeto de exemplo](https://github.com/eskimoapps/ResourceNestingExample)

Aqui um exemplo do bloco no arquivo `build.gradle` do projeto exemplo, os subpastas são declaradas antes.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
        [
                'src/main/res/layouts/layouts_category2',
                'src/main/res/layouts',
                'src/main/res'
        ]
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que te ajude.

**Fonte**: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)

Comment: Então eu até vi essa questão no stack gringo, eu não cheguei a abrir o projeto do cara no github (vou abrir agora) mas depois que eu fiz isso, comecou a dar pau lá nos arquivos do java..... eu vou dar uma olhada no projeto do cara pra ver como ele referencia essa questão lá

Comment: Utilizo igual este exemplo e funciona tudo. Faz o teste ai.

Comment: É acabei de ver. 1 coisa que eu fazia errado. Eu tentava usar a pasta "layout" depois que eu percebi que ele cria outra pasta nomeada de layouts... Fiz igual e funcionou. Valeu pelo help!

Comment: Como eu crio as pastas em si? fiz isso no gradle mas as pastas nao aparece dentro de layout